# Flutter: Detecting Face from Image URL and Cropping Profile Picture

Tags: flutter, dart, face-detection

I am building an app where I want to show a profile picture, but I only want the face to be visible in the image. However, currently, the entire image is visible in my app. I have the image URL, and I want to use Flutter code to detect the face in the image.

I have tried using the faceDetector.processImage() method, but I am not getting any results. I am not sure if I am using the correct parameters or if there is something else I need to do.

Comment: please edit your question and include the reproducible code